# Is there a canonical Q&A that explains TypeScript's type erasure and compile time vs run time behaviour?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I see ***a lot*** of questions who expect TypeScript to simply do something it cannot. They are based on a fundamental misunderstanding about what TypeScript does and how it works. The whole type system only exists at compile time, yet I see times and times again questions that expect:

- run time errors on a type mismatch. For example, requesting data over AJAX, declaring that the response would be of interface A but the server returns `null` or type B.
- type assertions to actually have a run time effect. For example, `"42" as number` to produce a number or even more often `myObjOfTypeA as B`.
- that types can be directly checked at run time. Like doing `myVar instanceof A`.
- the compiler to do deductions based on run time logic. For example, a function with signature `(bool: boolean) => A | B` and implementation `const fn = bool ? <something of type A> : <something of type B>`. Then expecting `fn(true)` to produce a result of type A.

All these do not and cannot work. So each question that asks for these or any other variation inherently suffer from a misunderstanding about *how* TypeScript works. This is covered by TypeScript resources like [the official FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure)<sup>1</sup>, however I was wondering there is a good canonical here that explains this. I tried to look around but failed.

- [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript/) is a good introduction but it's not explicit enough about compile time and run time difference.
- [Casting a number to a string in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554624/casting-a-number-to-a-string-in-typescript) deals directly with only one of the issues.
- [How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript) is a very good look "behind the scenes" and does clarify that there exists the *ambient* context. Essentially, that's the compile time information that is not retained for runtime. However, while *really good*, the focus isn't to clarify ambient (compile time) vs real (run time) contexts. Similar problem with the focus here

  - [What does 'declare' do in 'export declare class Actions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions)
  - [What means "ambient" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript)

Seeing how often this comes up, I thought there would be something that directly focuses on explaining the compile/run time difference similar to [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) yet I can't seem to find one. Am I missing failing at searching here? If it doesn't exist, I am also content with writing a self-answered Q&A myself or anybody else would also be welcome to, I would just prefer to have a singular on-site target.

<sup>1</sup> As a side note, the FAQ also has a section called [Common "Bugs" That Aren't Bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs). It's the very first thing in the FAQ. So, TypeScript does have its problem with misunderstandings.

Comment: Ping me if you wrote the QA, will add a bounty ... :) (only if it's a good one though)

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm afraid writing one is going to take a while because I want it to be good. But also...I've other priorities myself, so I'm not going to do it right now. It's partly why I'm looking for a canonical. Still, if/when I do it, I'll be sure to give you a shout.

Comment: This bleeds into bad mental models of how other parts of the ecosystem work, too; see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel like TypeScript is partly at fault here. Or sort of at fault. It is marketed as "JavaScript with types" and many people repeat that statement without making it clear enough that TypeScript produces JavaScript, so the code you write in is not what runs. Without being familiar with JS, or TS it's not very logical that half the code you wrote isn't actually "real" and doesn't exist at runtime. `const foo: string = 42 as string;` emits `const foo = 42` and it's definitely surprising, without knowing what the compiler does or why.

Comment: They currently open with *"TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript."* Where they introduce things like type assertions, they explicitly call out *"A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler."* Also it does know that `42 as string` won't work! You'd have to do e.g. `42 as unknown as string`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure...but it requires reading the official documentation. In my experience, people who are generally unfamiliar with JavaScript are just told "use TypeScript" and given a bunch of front-end tasks to implement because TS "should be easy". This leads to many issues. Even if they lookup an article, it needs not be the official handbook or even a good article. By comparison JS, even with its many gotchas, can just run and behaviour can be directly observed. With TS the level of indirection imposed by the compilation makes building a good understanding more difficult.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so, to just "start writing TS" and *understand* what happens, is to look at the compiled code. Which, again, would be a problem for people unfamiliar with JS. It's now a semi-closed circle - in order to understand TS you need to understand JS. Or TS. If you know neither, getting into is very hard. Reading articles that say "this is like type casting but it's a type assertion" may as well say "it's gobbledigook but actually jibber-jabber" for all the clarity brings. As evidenced by the many questions we have RTFM doesn't work. We can at least streamline the responses to that.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ there's only so much responsibility a tool can take for poor management, laziness and incompetence on the part of those using it. They can't take any for the material third parties post on Medium (neither rare, nor well done). Yes, you need to understand JS to understand TS, I don't think *"people unfamiliar with JS"* is the target market. I'm not saying a canonical post isn't a good idea from a moderation perspective, though I suspect the same people who didn't read everything else won't read that either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe We have a canonical for server/client-side code and why mixing the two doesn't work. Server/client-side programming is a fairly well understood and documented topic, I'd say way better than TS. Yet, the question still gets a lot of links. I don't see this being different - lots of confusion is evident right now. I wish it weren't so, however I must work with the situation. We're building a repository of knowledge here and this seems like an area that we have a hole in.

Comment: Again, I'm *not* saying there shouldn't be a canonical post on this.

Comment: The fourth one is not in the same category of question, and is perfectly possible to implement in Typescript: the function's type can be refined to `<T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends true ? A : B`, or using function overloads `(x: true): A` and `(x: false): B`.

Comment: @kaya3 the example was shortened for brevity but it comes from multiple real questions I've seen where people genuinely thought the compiler *must* know that `fn(true)` produces `A` and were asking how come that didn't work in reality. The answer is the same - it's behaviour that depends on runtime information. There is an extra layer that TS doesn't even check the implementation because the compiler just knows the signature - you could implement it as `fn2 = _ => Math.random() < 0.5 ? <type A> : <type B>` and the result there cannot be statically predicted.

Comment: I don't think the answer is the same at all. The problem in that case can be solved simply by refining the type so that the compiler can derive the stricter type for the expression at compile-time. Making it work would never require having the `boolean` type itself represented at runtime. It fits into a different category of question, of the form *"why doesn't Typescript infer a stricter type than the one I've declared?"* where the answer is that you need to declare a stricter type.

Comment: @kaya3 depends whether the question is "how do I make `fn(true)` always produce type A" or whether it's "I have `fn(true)` but it doesn't produce <type A>. Why is that". Even in the former case, there is (usually) lack of understanding or knowledge about *why* `fn(true)` doesn't return `A`. So, understanding and properly conceptually separating compile time types and run time behaviour is a very important step.

Comment: But the answer is not "it's impossible because `boolean` has no runtime representation", and the answer is not even "it's impossible". The fourth example is out-of-place because the function actually *does* have the correct behaviour at runtime, and it's just a matter of how to convince Typescript of that fact.

Comment: @kaya3 sure, and not every time somebody does `0.1 + 0.2` should the answer be an explanation about floating point arithmetic. But without the important background, any explanation is either going to just be repeating information or omitting said information. Both seem flawed - if you repeat the information it's 1. tedious 2. prone to errors. We have dupes to avoid repetition of answers. If you omit the information and just say "do this", then people reading the solution don't actually come up with a useful long term knowledge.